# How do I put color on a virtual string tree node?

Tags: delphi, string, tree, virtual

Is it possible for a virtual string tree to look like this?

[alt text http://sphotos.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash2/hs142.ash2/40454_1457947221163_1607860397_31141943_5530616_n.jpg](http://sphotos.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash2/hs142.ash2/40454_1457947221163_1607860397_31141943_5530616_n.jpg)

i really need help on this since i'm new in delphi..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put something in then `OnBeforeCellPaint` event. For instance:

```
procedure TForm1.VirtualStringTree1BeforeCellPaint(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree;      
    TargetCanvas: TCanvas; Node: PVirtualNode;
    Column: TColumnIndex; CellPaintMode: TVTCellPaintMode; CellRect: TRect; 
var     
  ContentRect: TRect);
begin
  CellRect.Left := CellRect.Left + 20;
  TargetCanvas.Brush.Color := clLime;
  TargetCanvas.RoundRect(CellRect, 5, 5);
  InflateRect(ContentRect, -1, -1);
end;
```

Would give you a crude approximation of what you have in the picture...

N@